Computing fundamental matrix for fisheye camera pair
I have a calibrated camera pair. If it was a camera which can be modeled with pinhole model, my approach would be the following:

Get essential matrix from (known) extrinsics
Get fundamental matrix from (again known) intrinsics and essential matrix
Compute epipolar lines (e.g. OpenCV's computeCorrespondEpilines) from the known 2D correspondences

For the camera with fisheye distortion, I would expect the following extension to the steps above:

Estimate new camera matrix for the undisorted image & undistort the images and 2D correspondences based on the known camera intrinsics
Proceed with all the steps above but for the undistorted images & points ...

Sadly, the result is that though epipolar lines seem to make sense, there is a significant distortion to them, and there is a big error between the epipolar line and the related corresponding point.
Is this procedure inherently wrong for the calibrated fisheye camera pair? Am I missing something?

When you say "get essential matrix from known extrinsics" are you using measurements, are you going from published data such as focal length, or are you using further data published by the camera maker?  There's a lot of different ways to make a fisheye lens, and a lot of ways to muck that up during the camera assembly.  I'd measure the camera's characteristics.
